# OWLOntologyStorer exception when creating an Ontology

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.addOntologyStorer(Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyStorer;)V

when I try to create an Ontology using the following line of code:

```
owlmanager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you have multiple OWLAPI versions on your classpath. This looks like OWLAPI 4 and OWLAPI 3 conflicts.